# Cannot call MessageBoxA in NASM assembly (crashes)

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86, nasm

I have created a small program in Assembly (NASM) for Windows 32-bit that call the WinAPI and opens a message box. The program crashes for some reason and I have no idea why, there must be some problem in the code but I cannot find it (addresses are correct for sure). Any ideas what may be the error and why?

```
[BITS 32]

section .data

section .text

    global  _start

_start:
    
    ; int MessageBox(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);

    xor   eax, eax
    push  eax
    push  0x74657374         ; string that says "test"
    mov   ecx, esp           ; pointer

    push  eax
    push  0x74657374         ; string that says "test"
    mov   edx, esp           ; pointer

    push  eax
    push  ecx
    push  edx
    push  eax
    mov   esi, 0x307be275    ; address to MessageBoxA
    call  esi

    xor   eax, eax 
    push  eax
    mov   eax, 0x778a9fe0    ; address to ExitProcess
    jmp   eax
```

Comment: Crashes where, on which instruction?  When you run this under a debugger, it should show you the faulting instruction and register values.

Comment: Pretty sure your strings are going to be backwards.

Comment: Addresses to WinAPI functions should point to thunks in import section, which they obviously don't, otherwise they would differ by several bytes only. Thunk contains an indirect JMP to address in IAT, which is set at load-time. Beside the asm source you should divulge how did you assemble and link your program.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error...

I had to import the function first.

Here is a correct version:

```
[BITS 32]

    extern _MessageBoxA@16    <---- This one is neccessary

section .data

section .text

    global  _start

_start:

   etc.
```